# Finding a common ID (value) in a normalized table based on several where clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, having

I have the following table (offer_properties) in MYSQL for an e-commerce website:

```
+----------+-------------+---------+
| offer_id | pkey        | pvalue  |
+----------+-------------+---------+
|       63 | shoesize    | shoe_47 |
|       63 | sport       | walking |
|       63 | color       | multi   |
|       12 | color       | multi   |
|       12 | shoesize    | size_48 |
|       12 | shoesize    | size_47 |
|       12 | shoesize    | size_46 |
|       12 | sneakertype | comfort |
|       12 | sport       | running |
+----------+-------------+---------+
```

What is the easiest way to find the offers where

```
shoesize = size_48 AND sport = running
```

I could do it by

```
select offer_id from offer_properties where (pkey = "sport" and pvalue = "running") and offer_id IN (select offer_id from offer_properties where (pkey = "shoesize" and pvalue = "size_48"));
```

However, this recursive approach makes it really difficult as there could be various property match requests. Moreover, I have other tables that I need to JOIN and the queries gets complicated quite quickly. I have one table that holds the values (price, description, etc.) and another normalized table that holds offer tags.

I `LEFT JOIN` to find the offers that matches certain tags with certain properties and with certain values. However, things get quite complicated very quikly.

What would be your guidance for such scenarios? Should I use simple queries with Promises and use the app logic to filter things step by step?

Many thanks

Comment: FWIW, EAV tables like the one you show are not normalized.

Comment: I did not know that thanks Bill. I will do some googling to better understand how to normalize.

Comment: You might like this blog I wrote which discusses it. The blog itself is short, but there is an extensive discussion in the comments. https://karwin.com/blog/index.php/2009/05/21/eav-fail/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `conditional aggregation` to avoid self-joins.

---

```
select offer_id
from (
  select offer_id, 
    sum(case when pkey = 'shoesize' and pvalue = 'size_48' then 1 else 0 end) cond1, 
    sum(case when pkey = 'sport' and pvalue = 'running' then 1 else 0 end) cond2
  from offer_properties
  group by offer_id
  )z
where cond1> 0 and cond2> 0;
```

| offer_id |
| --- |
| 12 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wYjiE7G9hA3qo9owbtTa6R/1)

Comment: Very interesting technique, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use quite simple self join:

```sql
select offer_id
from offer_properties o1
where pkey = "sport"
  and pvalue = "running"
  and exists (
        select 1
        from offer_properties o2
        where o2.offer_id = o1.offer_id
        and o2.pkey = "shoesize"
        and o2.pvalue = "size_48"
        );
```

Or you could use `EXIST`. It quite similar to your current query.

```sql
select offer_id
from offer_properties o1
join offer_properties o2
on (o2.offer_id = o1.offer_id
        and o2.pkey = "shoesize"
        and o2.pvalue = "size_48")
where pkey = "sport"
  and pvalue = "running";
```

Both solutions require additional constructions, but with current model, I believe you have no chance avoiding it.

On the other hand, I would argue that exists (as your current query) could be written in a single line, and should not clutter your query to much.

Answer (score 0):

No need for joins, nor for subqueries. We can do direct filtering on aggregates with a `having` clause:

```
select offer_id
from offer_properties
group by offer_id
having max(pkey = 'shoesize' and pvalue = 'size_48') = 1
   and max(pkey = 'sport'    and pvalue = 'running') = 1
```